# First click doesn't work after navigating to a page

Tags: silverlight, navigation, focus

I have a Silverlight application that is using the Navigation Framework.  The page is never focused right after it is navigated too. So when I first click on a button, it does nothing (except focus the page).  Only the second click after navigation works.  I use a subclass of the `Page` and have hooked the `GotFocus` event.  It is never called.  I've also tried to call the `Focus` method a handler for the `Loaded` event and the override to `OnNavigatedTo`.  Nothing works.  The `GotFocus` handler is never called until I actually click somewhere in the view.  My clients are not going to accept this.  Is this a bug with the Navigation Framework, is there a work around?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Is this only on the first page load?

Comment: This occurs whenever a page is navigated to by the Navigation Framework.

Comment: Most unusual. Do you have an example project showing the problem?

Comment: Hmm... it's quite a lot of code. I can post the sub class I mentioned.